# Systemd unit for bus devices

Tags: systemd, usb

Is there a way to run a systemd unit when a `/sys/bus` path is available? I'm trying to automate the following command on an embedded device:

```bash
echo "on" >  /sys/bus/usb/devices/usb1/power/control
```

However I'm getting an error; by looking at the journal the output is:

```
can't create /sys/bus/usb/devices/usb1/power/control: nonexistent directory
```

I also tried to search for existing USB units but nothing for that type of devices comes up if I run `systemctl --all --full -t device`.

Comment: Put a watch on with `udevadm monitor`. This will show you info on devices and their paths as you connect/disconnect them. `man udevadm` for more

Answer (score 0):

The service you are looking for is called `udev`. This service receives kernel events on device changes and has a rules engine that let's you do things if some conditions are true for a certain event, see [the fine manual](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/udev.html#).

You should be able to find some examples in your `/etc/udev/` directory. You are probably looking for something starting with

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ACTION=="add"
```

and you probably want to finish with something like

```
RUN+="echo "on" >  /sys/bus/usb/devices/usb1/power/control"
```

There are variables you may use in `RUN` so you don't have to hardcode the whole thing.